# Flutter bottom padding color on iPhone

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

is it possible to change the color of this bottom padding that comes with the iPhone ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Wrap your** *MaterialApp* **with below code in `main.dart` class**:-

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, //set as per your  status bar color
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black, //set as per your navigation bar color
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, //set as per your status bar icons' color
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      child: MaterialApp(
```

Comment: That did not help, its still the same :/

Comment: it looked like SafeArea widget was the reason behind this behavior, I wrapped it with a container and gave it a color, all good now :)