# status bar doesn't change background color in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two pages first one have white status bar and the second page has gray status bar but when I move from one to another page the second page takes first status bar color ??

**NOTE :** when I run the second page from main function it takes the right color

I use this for status bar :

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
        statusBarColor: Color(0xffF6F6F6), 
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark 
));
```

what is the reason for this ?

Comment: Did you set this update inside a setState ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65609678/11404883

Comment: @BabC No , where should I set update?

Comment: @AR thank you so much it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try out this:-**

**Wrap your MaterialApp with below code in main.dart class:-**

```html
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, //set as per your  status bar color
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black, //set as per your navigation bar color
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark, //set as per your status bar icons' color
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ),
      child: MaterialApp(
```

**And if you want change appbar color of whole app then try out below**

```html
theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            appBarTheme: Theme.of(context)
                .appBarTheme
                .copyWith(brightness: Brightness.light),
        ),
```

Comment: can I ask another question about status bar but another situation

Comment: I have home page and it has drawer and app bar 
status bar doesn't appear and this solution doesn't work with it

Comment: @LailaMattar can you please give me image so i can get some idea ?

Comment: @LailaMattar I added some code related appbar above you can try out this.:)